# PPTPd only routing to eth0

Tags: ubuntu, routing, pptp

How do I enable routing to eth0 without having the ability to communicate amongst pptp clients? I know ip_forward = 1 makes routing of pptp clients possible, but i dont want communication under pptp clients.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to block traffic between users by packet filter.

Comment: You have any suggestion on how to achieve this using for iptables for example? My clients are connection using ppp0,ppp1,pppX and outgoing interface is eth0

Comment: It would be more simple of your assign IPs to clients from dedicated subnet, so all you need is one rule per interface to deny traffic on given interface (pppX) to given subnet

Comment: all pppX devices get an ip 192.168.50.0/24 and the eth0 is on a wan ip. I also cant seem to get internet traffic over my pptp tunnel. ip_forward is on...

Comment: Seem to have fixed that now using  `iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.50.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE`; Now only thing remaining is to block traffic between 192.168.50.0/24 clients...

Comment: All you need is something like `iptables -A INPUT -i ppp0 -d 192.168.50.0/24 -j REJECT` somewhere in /etc/ppp/ip-up.d/

Comment: Worked like a charm :)